# Android game layout responsive

Tags: java, responsive-design, android-imageview, autoresize

I want to create simple android game layout which contains some `ImageViews` .
I set their width and height in `dp` type according to my layout psd resource file.
the result was my desire in my own device (which has 480*800 resolution and 4" screen size) but when i test it another device with larger screen size and resoultion , imageviews's sizes are the same as my own device and most of the space became empty . what should i do to make imageviews responsive according to screen size ?